# validation for multiple forms generated by loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a for loop that generates 5 forms.There is lot of animation involved and only one form is displayed at a time.

[My link](http://staging.experiencecommerce.com/ecsite-v3/html/career.php)

I have done the validation which is *id based* on some other page(working fine).
But here the situation is different,I cannot generate id because of the loop.So my entire form validation is to be class based.

**Myquestion:** How do I manage a single function which validates all 5 forms.

If you are interested in my id based code-> this is thefiddle (not working),just the basic [code](http://jsfiddle.net/8fMPx/1/)

My code:for simplicity

```
for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
//html of my form in fiddle.
}
```

New to jquery.I do understand $(this) concept in jquery.

Hope I am clear.No plugin plz.

Comment: What problems did you have with making it class-based? Please show us your attempts.

Comment: @Bergi:ok wait for 5 min..i will bring up a fiddle..but I have lots of animation ..I am looking for module..just an idea..not the entire code..I have done the validation..but dont know what to do in this case...

Comment: Your html is not valid, use a real form (with `<form>`) tag and use the [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) jQuery event. This is not a solution, but that seems cleaner.

Comment: i am using a foreach loop which generates a form..without form tag..its perfectly fine..i can give you the link if you want..http://staging.experiencecommerce.com/ecsite-v3/html/career.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, if an element is not unique do not use an ID for it.

Let's say we have 2 forms here:

```
<form id="formOne" class="validForm" method="post">
    <input class="email" type="text"/>
    <input class="newsletter" type="checkbox"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    <p class="error"></p>
</form>

<form id="formTwo" class="validForm" method="post">
    <input class="email" type="text"/>
    <input class="newsletter" type="checkbox"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    <p class="error"></p>
</form>
```

It's important to know your form elements are parents of your input or select elements. So when you use `$(this)` you can refer back to the parent.

To validate this in jQuery:

```
$('.validForm').submit(function(event){
    var allInputsAreValid = true;
    var form = null;
    $('.validForm input').each(function(){
        switch($(this).attr('class')){
            case 'email':
                if($(this).val() == "") {
                    allInputsAreValid = false;
                }
            break;
            case 'newsletter':
                // optional?
            break;
        }
        if(!allInputsAreValid) {
            form = $(this).parent();
            break;
        }
    });
    if(allInputsAreValid){
      // everything is valid, transfer data
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(form).children('.error').text(errorMessage);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, which is wrong since you want to have a form. I'm trying to teach you a mindset, not something you can copy.

Comment: Happy to hear, if so you can apply this way to your own situation.

Comment: if possible please have a look at my html..i am using href for subitting which ok..i also have a plugin uplick.js which uploads on href click..ok i will figure out..have a look at the link in my question that i updated..thx for the answer

Comment: If you have an `<a>` instead of a `<form>` just change submit to click and the selector to match the `<a>` and put the `event.preventDefault()` up top.

Answer (score -3):

You mentioned you didn't want any plugins, which is fine. But I think you could learn a few things from going through the source code of an existing validation plugin like [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html). I did, and I used what I learned to do a much simpler validation for my forms.

Basically it works by data-* tags to define what kind of input to expect from each field, then you can just loop through them like I assume you were already doing.

Example from the documentation:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" data-trigger="change" data-required="true" data-type="email" />
```

Hope it helps.